# 2 numeric stepper components in an item renderer of flex

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, time, itemrenderer, numericstepper

I have to put 2 numeric stepper components in one column of a datagrid. I suppose I need to write my own item renederer code for that. How to write a code for putting 2 numeric stepper components in one coulmn of datagrid.

The 2 numeric steppers would work as time (Hour and Min) components. I cannot use readily availabel time components, and hence have to write something of the above for my own time component.

Answer (score 1):

That correct, you need to create an item renderer. With Flex, this is relatively easy.

[Here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=cellrenderer_3.html) is an article on how to do it.

Comment: I have read that documentation. But, it does not specifically mention of how to go about for 2 numeric stepper components. can you help with some code ?

Comment: Also, is it anyways possible to have "00" "00" in numeric stepper ?

Comment: I could insert 2 numeric stepper components in a row. I have following issues :

1> The numeric stepper does not get displayed unless row is clicked.
2> The component is being displayed only for first row, inspte of having many other rows.
3> Can we have "00" and "00" in the numeric stepper.

Comment: 4> Since, it is a time component, I have to increment minutes by 5, now, it goes fine from 0-5-10-15-20-15......but, I keep max 59, inorder that it loops back to 0 instead of showing 60, but it displays 59. can we loop back in the numeric stepper value, so that after 55-00 is available ?

please help me sort above issues. Please

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
<mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Unit Price" dataField="price">
    <mx:itemRenderer>
        <mx:Component>
            <mx:NumericStepper ... />
            <mx:NumericStepper ... />
        </mx:Component>
    </mx:itemRenderer>
</mx:DataGridColumn>
```

Or you could set the itemRenderer to a custom component

I.E.

```
<mx:DataGridColumn itemRenderer="com.myComponent" headerText="Unit Price" dataField="price">
```

(note you might need {com.myComponent} ... not sure on the syntax, just going off memory)

For your specific example I would probably create my own component with a mask like ##:## then use that as the item renderer.

Answer (score 0):

[Peter Ent's series](http://weblogs.macromedia.com/pent/archives/2008/03/itemrenderers_p.html) on itemRenderers is a MUST for any Flex developer.

Comment: Link is no longer valid. This seems to be the correct link: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/itemrenderers_pt1.html